# Is it possible to remove irrelevant restrictions from paket.lock?

Tags: f#, dependency-management, paket

I have discovered that my `paket.lock` file contains a lot of things I don't care about, e.g.:

```
System.Memory (>= 4.5.3) - restriction: || 
(&& (< monoandroid) (< monotouch) (< net45) (>= netstandard1.3) (< netstandard2.0) (< win8) (< wpa81) (< xamarintvos) (< xamarinwatchos)) 
(&& (< net45) (< netcoreapp2.1) (>= netstandard2.0) (< xamarinios) (< xamarinmac)) 
(>= net46) 
(>= uap10.1)
```

I don't want to think about `monoandroid` or `wpa81` or `uap10.1` and so on and it is hard to understand what is really going on there after I have recently got some dependency conflict. I want something neat e.g. like [this](https://github.com/SAFE-Stack/SAFE-Nightwatch/blob/master/paket.lock).

I read some docs and tried the [framework restriction](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/dependencies-file.html#Framework-restrictions) thing in `paket.dependencies`: `framework: netstandard20, netcoreapp30`.
But it did not really change much after `paket install`. I have tried adding this to every group - to no avail as well. I tried running `paket update` and `paket simplify`, I tried to remove the lock file and to `paket install` everything again.

Am I doing something wrong, like not adding directions to `paket.dependencies` or running wrong `paket` command?

Or is it just the way things are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These declarations in the `paket.lock` file aren't irrelevant. You're seeing this because the `System.Memory` package you're depending on, either directly or implicitly, has [a lot of targets it can run on](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/). Paket is resolving the package and correctly serializing the resolution rules. Should you do something like multi-target in the future, and one of those targets isn't supported for the package, you'll correctly get a package resolution failure. However, if you delete these, you'll likely end up with a runtime failure.